# Unable to access a file copied in a container

Tags: file, permissions, docker

I am tryng to run a java application in a container. In my docker file I copy the jar file and then run the jar

```
ADD project.jar /tmp/project.jar
CMD java -jar /tmp/project.jar
```

This fails with the following error `Error: Unable to access jarfile /tmp/projct.jar`  However if I run the image with bash and manually navigate t o /tmp and run the `java -jar` command it works. Are there any more configurations I need to follow?

Comment: tried copying it in /local, smae error

Comment: Why do you "manually navigate to /tmp"? What happens when you run it the same as in your Dockerfile: `java -jar /tmp/project.jar` ?

Comment: Paste the real error.

Comment: If that is the actual error, then it's likely you made a typo in your Dockerfile and the `CMD` line isn't as posted (but rather names the file `projct.jar` as in your error - instead of `project.jar`)

Comment: Time to get a break dude...

Comment: That was exactly the issue! Sorry!